# C# langversion at 7.3 but IDE still allows me to add ?? (null-coalescing operator)

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, c#-7.3

I'm using C# 7.3 on Visual Studio 2019 (Version 16.9.2).  The IDE allows me to use the null-coalescing operator and it builds without errors.

I don't have a `Directory.Build.props` file anywhere and I have the following in my csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I expect this limits me to C# version 7.3, and when I confirm with [`#error version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#override-a-default) I see this:

> Error CS8304  Compiler version: '3.9.0-6.21160.10 (59eedc33)'. Language version: 7.3.

So I know I really am using C# 7.3.

Why can I still use the `??` null-coalescing operator? Any troubleshooting tips?

Comment: c# 7.3 _does_ support the null coalesce operator, so what's the problem? (don't confuse it with the null _assignment_ operator `??=`, which was added in 8.0)

Comment: I'm confused. I see both "It builds without errors" and also "It gives me error CS8304". Which is it?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn `#error version` is a way of getting the compiler version, which is presented as CS8304

Comment: `??=` was added in C# 8 -- maybe you're getting confused with that? `??` has been around since C# 2

Comment: Got it. Edited to clarify.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann yeah, got confused by ?? and ??=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from the [official documentation on the operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator):

> In C# 7.3 and earlier, the type of the left-hand operand of the ?? operator must be either a reference type or a nullable value type. Beginning with C# 8.0, that requirement is replaced with the following: the type of the left-hand operand of the ?? and ??= operators cannot be a non-nullable value type.

In other words, the null coalescing operator does exist and is allowed in C# 7.3 and prior. Using C# 7.3 only limits you from putting a regular value type (struct or primitive) on the left side. Even here, the distinction between the two is subtle.

Basically, the only restriction in either situation is you must have a left-hand operand that is actually allowed to be `null`.

Comment: My bad, read the documentation wrong. Didn't scroll down far enough.